# Unable to open file to write using specified name, but not another

Tags: matlab, save, mat

I get an error with this code

```
>> save([params.datapath '/' configfilename{1}],'params')
Error using save
Unable to open file "C:\Users\Rik\Desktop\mps
project\ColdComplaintData/Data/filename-config_30-Jan-2016_20:25:46.mat" for output.
```

but not this code

```
>> save([params.datapath '/' 'ddd.mat'],'params')
```

What is the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Use `fullfile` to concatenate file path, this prevents you from mixing \ and /. Not the cause of this problem, but a potential cause of other problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows doesn't allow filenames with colons (:) in them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
The following reserved characters:
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon)
" (double quote)
/ (forward slash)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```